# Who is nighasa? Was he a worshiper of lord shiva?

Tags: scripture, vishnu, shiva, asuras

Who is nighasa i listened he swalowed lord vishnu and he got this boon from lord bramha? Is he mentioned in any scripture?

And was he a worshiper of lord shiva?